# Trouble With JS Closure

Tags: javascript, oop, closures

I have this js:

```
(function () {

    Namespace = {

        settings: {
            myVar: 'test' 
        },

        init: function() {

            var memberSearchFrm = document.getElementById('memberSearch');
            memberSearchFrm.onsubmit = function() {

                this.someOtherFunction(); // doesn't work
                console.log(this.settings.myVar); // doesn't work 
            }
         },

        someOtherFunction: function() {
            console.log('test');  
        }
    }

    Namespace.init();
})();
```

I'm losing the context of 'this' when I go into my onSubmit function. Can you help me understand why this is happening and how to work around this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the this that trick.

Before you closure set a variable called 'that' to this.

```
var that = this;
```

Then use that in you closure. The problem you have having is that the closure is attached to you DOM node and not your object. So when you closure was called this had the value of the DOM node.

Comment: I would recommend calling it `self`.

Comment: I like self better too but I think that 'that' is a more Java like solution and everyone wants JavaScript to be Java.

Comment: also self is a keyword in javascript referencing the current window - http://jsfiddle.net/GvKZ4/

Comment: If you use var self = this than self is only in scope within the function.

Answer (score 3):

Inside `memberSearchFrm.onsubmit`, `this` refers to `memberSearchFrm`, not to the object you want.  You need to save a reference to `this`.

```
    init: function() {
        var that = this;
        var memberSearchFrm = document.getElementById('memberSearch');
        memberSearchFrm.onsubmit = function() {
            that.someOtherFunction();
            console.log(that.settings.myVar); 
        }
     },
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same issue with closures and made this fiddle to experiment with different ways to call other functions in a closure.

http://jsfiddle.net/7FzEz/5/

I finally settled with this format:

```
(function () {

     var obj = {

        settings: {
            myVar: 'test' 
        },

        init: function() {

            var memberSearchFrm = document.getElementById('memberSearch');
            memberSearchFrm.onsubmit = function() {

                obj.someOtherFunction(); 
                console.log(obj.settings.myVar);  
            }
         },

        someOtherFunction: function() {
            console.log('test');  
        }
    }

    obj.init();
})();
```

Comment: Namespace was just a placeholder name to use in my example. What advantage does putting in var give it? It works either way, j/c...

Comment: Actually, none in your case since you are in an anonymous wrapper, and I will edit it here. When you are not in an anonymous wrapper then it matters - see the bane of global variables under scope here: http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#function.scopes

Comment: Now I take it back, adding var in does make a difference since it keeps you from poluting your global name space: http://jsfiddle.net/vtPuE/

Comment: Of course.... if you wanted to assign it to that namespace in the global context you don't want var which is maybe what you were after?